# Add URL params to link_to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the simple was to pass params to rails link_to?

**routes.rb**

```
get '/users/:user_id/accounts/hires/:hire_id/release' => 'hire_milestones#release', as: 'release_hire_milestone'
```

html:

```
<% @foo.map do |f| %>
  <b><%= m.reason %></b> at <b>£<%= m.amount_requested %></b>
    <span><%= link_to 'a', release_hire_milestone_path(:user_id, :hire_id, amount: f.bar), class: "tiny button", method: :get %></span> <br/>
<% end %>
```

The actual web url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/accounts/hires/40
```

When I mouse over the button, it shows:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/user_id/accounts/hires/hire_id/release?amount=860
```

How to add more than one params to a link_to's path?

**SOLVED:**

I needed to change:

```
<%= link_to 'a', release_hire_milestone_path(:user_id, :hire_id, amount: f.bar), class: "tiny button", method: :get %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to 'a', release_hire_milestone_path(params[:user_id], params[:hire_id], amount: f.bar), class: "tiny button", method: :get %>
```

But a slight error in route: `hire_id` should be `id`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing it the right way apart from a little glitch.

You are really passing the params, but you are not specifying the values yet.

What you need to do is to pass the values of the both the `user_id` and the `hire_id`, just the way you are passing the `amount`.

Something like the following:

```
<% @foo.map do |f| %>
  <b><%= m.reason %></b> at <b>£<%= m.amount_requested %></b>
    <span><%= link_to 'a', release_hire_milestone_path(user_id: <value_of_user_id>, hire_id: <value_of_hire_id>, amount: f.bar), class: "tiny button", method: :get %></span> <br/>
<% end %>
```

Assuming there is the `@hire` and `@user` objects available for you on the current view... and the `user_id` is the `@user.id` and `hire_id` is the `@hire.id`, then the above could be written as follow:

```
<% @foo.map do |f| %>
  <b><%= m.reason %></b> at <b>£<%= m.amount_requested %></b>
    <span><%= link_to 'a', release_hire_milestone_path(user_id: @user.id, hire_id: @hire.id, amount: f.bar), class: "tiny button", method: :get %></span> <br/>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah! Ill have a go later today as im not around my laptop. Ill report later.

Comment: This is what worked without issues: `<%= link_to 'a', release_hire_milestone_path(@user.id, @hire.id, amount: f.bar), class: "tiny button", method: :get %>`

Comment: Ive marked your answer but make the changes to reflect what works for me